# Very very simple qtip implementation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, qtip2, qtip

I want to create tooltips with qTip but they have a lot of ridiculous examples on their page that is waaaaaaaaaaay to complicated.

I want something like:

```
<span qtip="This is the text in my tooltip">This text has a tooltip</span>
```

is that possible?

The $(document).ready is not an option since I have a loop with several cells that needs tooltips all of them.

Meta code:

```
foreach Customer in List<Customers>
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span qtip="Tooltip for Name">Customer.Name</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span qtip="Tooltip for Address">Customer.Address</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span qtip="Tooltip for Phonenumber">Customer.Phonenumber</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Is this possible with qtip or is there something else that can generate nice looking tooltips that works similar to the above?

Thanks for all help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs suggest you should be able to use the following JS:

```
$('[qtip!=""]').qtip({
  content: {
    attr: 'qtip'
  }
});
```

This should grab all elements with a `qtip` attribute, and apply `qTip` to them.

Though I'm curious what you mean by

> The $(document).ready is not an option since I have a loop with several cells that needs tooltips all of them.

Are you saying your list of customers is added to dynamically without reloading the page? If so please show where that happens.

For safety you should really use `$(document).ready` if your customer list doesn't change.

Here's an example based on the question:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[qtip!=""]').qtip({
    content: {
      attr: 'qtip'
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/qtip2/3.0.3/basic/jquery.qtip.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/qtip2/3.0.3/basic/jquery.qtip.min.css">

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span qtip="Tooltip for Name">Customer.Name</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span qtip="Tooltip for Address">Customer.Address</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span qtip="Tooltip for Phonenumber">Customer.Phonenumber</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Sorry, all their examples show $(document).ready(function() 
{
   // By suppling no content attribute, the library uses each elements title attribute by default
   $('#content a[href]').qtip({
      // Simply use an HTML img tag within the HTML string
      content: 'i am a qtip'
   });
}); But that wont work since I might have 100 columns there.

Comment: No I don't add customer dynamically after the page is loaded. Maybe I don't really understand how the function in the document.ready works then.

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() { ... })` simply means - execute this function AFTER the document has finished rendering and is ready to go.

Comment: you could just add a `title` tag to your spans that will generate a 'tooltip'

Comment: Then I really don't understand how to do it. Since it seems to me that inside the document.read function they find a specific <span> or <href> or <div> and add a tooltip to *that specifically* and that's not a possibily for me since I will have anything from 3 to 300 columns in my example above.

Comment: The `$('[qtip!=""]').qtip();` example I have given you will find every element (no matter the type) that has a `qtip` attribute. It will work for your given example.

Comment: Hm. This is slightly above my head in Javascript I think I will try. Very exciting.

Comment: Please see my answer again, I've edited it to resolve the issue in your jsfiddle.

Comment: OMG! Thanks a gazillion! I humbly bow to you.